# Did flutter methodchannel support return a List<Map<String, String>> value?

Tags: flutter-animation

as title said, I wrote an plugin that return a List> value, but I can't get the result from my plugin, and there was no error.

Is any thing wrong?

How to implement the customized type returned by MethodChannel?

Answer (score 2):

**DO NOT:**

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> resp = await _channel.invokeMethod('returnAMapList');
```

**DO:**

```
List<Map> = await _channel.invokeMethod('returnAMapList');
```